# How can i improve my multithreading speed and effciency in python?

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrent.futures

How can improve my multithreading speed in my code?

My code takes 130 seconds with 100 threads to do 700 requests which is really slow and frustrating assuming that i use 100 threads.

My code edits the parameter values from an url and makes a request to it including the original url (unedited) the urls are received from a file (urls.txt)

Let me show you an example:

Let's consider the following url:

`https://www.test.com/index.php?parameter=value1&parameter2=value2`

The url contains 2 parameters so my code will make 3 requests.

1 request to the original url:

`https://www.test.com/index.php?parameter=value1&parameter2=value2`

1 request to the first modified value:

`https://www.test.com/index.php?parameter=replaced_value&parameter2=value2`

1 request to the second modified value:

`https://www.test.com/index.php?parameter=value1&parameter2=replaced_value`

I have tried using `asyncio` for this but I had more success with `concurrent.futures`

I even tried increasing the threads which I thought it was the issue at first but in this case wasnt if I would increase the threads considerably then the script would freeze at start for 30-50 seconds and it really didnt increased the speed as i expected

I assume this is a code issue how I build up the multithreading becuase I saw other people achieved incredible speeds with  concurrent.futures

```
import requests
import uuid
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed
import time

start = time.time()

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}
def make_request(url2):
    try:
        if '?' and '=':
            request_1 = requests.get(url2, headers=headers, timeout=10)
            url2_modified = url2.split("?")[1]
            times = url2_modified.count("&") + 1
            for x in range(0, times):
                split1 = url2_modified.split("&")[x]
                value = split1.split("=")[1]
                parameter = split1.split("=")[0]
                url = url2.replace('='+value, '=1') 
                request_2 = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=headers, timeout=10)
                html_1 = request_1.text
                html_2 = request_2.text
                print(request_1.status_code + ' - ' + url2)
                print(request_2.status_code + ' - ' + url)

    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
       return e


def runner():
    threads= []
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=100) as executor:
        file1 = open('urls.txt', 'r', errors='ignore')
        Lines = file1.readlines()   
        count = 0
        for line in Lines:
            count += 1
            threads.append(executor.submit(make_request, line.strip()))
      
runner()

end = time.time()
print(end - start)
```

Comment: Note that threads can't be used to run multiple CPU-bound tasks at once, so the only speedup you'll get from multithreading is from being able to make multiple requests at once. The processing of the data will only happen on one thread at once. You'd need multiprocessing to get around the GIL. Also note that `if '?' and '='`, besides missing a `:`, is equivalent to `if True`. I think you meant to compare against a variable, or use `in`?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Thanks for the info, appreciate it!. Yes during editing i think i forgot to put the :. Edited it now. Thanks again!

Comment: sometimes only solution is faster computer and faster internet - or faster server in internet which has faster connection then local computer.

Comment: inside `make_request` you run many `requests.get` in loop - so they don't use threads or any other method to make it faster. Every request in this loop has to wait for end of previous request. You should run every `requests.get` in separated thread (or using `asyncio`) to make it faster.

Comment: Ya, asyncio will let you make many requests at once on a single thread. It has a bit of a learning curve, and it won't speedup the processing at all, but it may be useful for making the requests faster without worrying about threading/multiprocessing.

Comment: @furas I guess that's the issue because i ran multiple get request in loop. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `loop` in `make_request` you run normal `requests.get` and it doesn't use `thread` (or any other method) to make it faster - so it has to wait for end of previous request to run next request.

In `make_request` I use another `ThreadPoolExecutor` to run every `requests.get`  (created in loop) in separated `thread`

```
executor.submit(make_modified_request, modified_url)
```

and it gives me time `~1.2s`

If I use normal

```
make_modified_request(modified_url)
```

then it gives me time `~3.2s`

---

Minimal working example:

I use real urls https://httpbin.org/get so everyone can simply copy and run it.

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import requests
import time
#import urllib.parse

# --- constansts --- (PEP8: UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

HEADERS = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/74.0.3729.131 Safari/537.36'}

# --- functions ---

def make_modified_request(url):
    """Send modified url."""

    print('send:', url)
    response = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers=HEADERS)
    print(response.status_code, '-', url)
    html = response.text   # ???
    # ... code to process HTML ...

def make_request(url):
    """Send normal url and create threads with modified urls."""

    threads = []

    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
            print('send:', url)

            # send base url            
            response = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS)
            print(response.status_code, '-', url)
            html = response.text   # ???

            #parts = urllib.parse.urlparse(url)
            #print('query:',  parts.query)
            #arguments = urllib.parse.parse_qs(parts.query)
            #print('arguments:', arguments)   # dict  {'a': ['A'], 'b': ['B'], 'c': ['C'], 'd': ['D'], 'e': ['E']}

            arguments = url.split("?")[1]
            arguments = arguments.split("&")
            arguments = [arg.split("=") for arg in arguments]
            print('arguments:', arguments)    # list [['a', 'A'], ['b', 'B'], ['c', 'C'], ['d', 'D'], ['e', 'E']]
             
            for name, value in arguments:
                modified_url = url.replace('='+value, '=1')
                print('modified_url:', modified_url)
                
                # run thread with modified url
                threads.append(executor.submit(make_modified_request, modified_url))
                
                # run normal function with modified url 
                #make_modified_request(modified_url)

    print('[make_request] len(threads):', len(threads))
    
def runner():
    threads = []
    
    with ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        #fh = open('urls.txt', errors='ignore')
        fh = [
            'https://httpbin.org/get?a=A&b=B&c=C&d=D&e=E', 
            'https://httpbin.org/get?f=F&g=G&h=H&i=I&j=J',
            'https://httpbin.org/get?k=K&l=L&m=M&n=N&o=O',
            'https://httpbin.org/get?a=A&b=B&c=C&d=D&e=E', 
            'https://httpbin.org/get?f=F&g=G&h=H&i=I&j=J',
            'https://httpbin.org/get?k=K&l=L&m=M&n=N&o=O',
           ]

        for line in fh:
            url = line.strip()
            # create thread with url
            threads.append(executor.submit(make_request, url))

    print('[runner] len(threads):', len(threads))

# --- main ---

start = time.time()

runner()

end = time.time()
print('time:', end - start)
```

---

**BTW:**

I was thinking to use single

```
executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10)
```

and later use the same `executor` in all functions - and maybe it would run little faster - but at this moment I don't have working code.